# Is it compulsory for a split button to have a Em-Class, with an attribute, unSelectable=On?

Tags: html, button, selenium, ria

I am writing this, with continuation to my previous posts...

[Where to click on this following object(button), for the values to be displayed in Selenium(Webdriver)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027312/where-to-click-on-this-following-objectbutton-for-the-values-to-be-displayed/)

[How to click in a specific part of a Button using Selenium, for the list of options to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994285/how-to-click-in-a-specific-part-of-a-button-using-selenium-for-the-list-of-opti)

As I wanted to automate a mouse click event for testing on a split button using selenium, upon clicking on one particular part of the button, I am finding that, 'that particular part' is present in an Em-class, which in turn has the button/link, but does nothing upon click...

This Em class has an attribute, unSelectable=On....Is this attribute necessary for a split button functionality?? Can it be given to Off??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I did not understand why in the first place the Em class has an attribute `unClickable="On"` .

I suggest you to change this value to `**unselectable="Off"**` and then look at what will happen.

Let me know if any errors are generated.

Comment: Thanks ...I talked with the developer and he is telling, it is essential for that option...! I found it difficult to convince him...Is that possible, I can do the change using Firebug and test it using Selenium??

Comment: question modified...it is unSelectable in the first place...not unClickable...! but, i ll try to do something abt. it from our end...